# Join 2 Columns with same ID in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

My problem is how can i join the selected rows with identical ID but different contacts

This is the output of what I'm doing

```
|     Name     |    Address   |     Cellphone    |     Email      | 
|     John     |     NY       |       n/a        |   johndoe@y.c  |
|     John     |     NY       |    123456781     |       n/a      |
```

and i want my output to be one liner combined

```
|     Name     |    Address   |     Cellphone    |     Email      | 
|     John     |     NY       |     123456781    |   johndoe@y.c  |
```

this is my Linq

```
var an = (from a in  db.Info
                     join b in db.Contact
                     on a.ID equals b.InfoID
                     where b.ContactTypeID == 56
                     || b.ContactTypeID == 59
                      select new
                                 {
                                     a.ID,
                                     a.LastName,
                                     a.FirstName,
                                     a.MiddleName,
                                     b.ContactTypeID,
                                     b.Values

                                 }).ToList();


            List<Info> wlist = new List<Info>();
            foreach (var row in an)
            {
                Info ci = new Info

                                           {

                                               ID = row.ID,
                                               Name = row.FirstName + " " + row.MiddleName + " " + row.LastName,
                                               ContactType = GetLookupDisplayValById(row.ContactTypeID),
                                               ContactValue = row.Values

                                           };
                wlist.Add(ci);
            }
            return Json(wlist.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I hope someone can help me with this

Thanks :)

Comment: You can count the ID, use the group by function in Linq for the contact, and then you'd get those Ids which have count greater than 1. It is a matter of joining then afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it:

```
from info in db.Info
join contact in db.Contact
on info.ID == contact.InfoID
select new Contact(info, contact)
```

And your constructor will merge.

```
public class Contact
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string MiddleName { get; set; }
public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }

public Contact(Info info, Contact contact)
{
   ID = info.ID;
   LastName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.LastName) ? contact.LastName : info.LastName;
}
}
```

Comment: sir where can i add the `select new { a.ID }` statements?

Comment: You class Contact should be your model.
With all properties that you would store in it.

Comment: can you please help me. with complete snippet :(

Comment: I update the exemple above, I hope you will understand what I try to explain !

Answer (score 0):

try with GroupBy

```
var resuts = db.Info.GroupBy(i=>i.ID)
 .Select(g=>new Info{
            ID = g.Key,
            Address = g.Fist().Address,
            Cellphone = g.FistOrDefault(x=> x.Cellphone !="n/a"),
            Email = g.FistOrDefault(x=> x.Email !="n/a")
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: sir im quite confused .. is the `g=>new Info` is the `List<Info>` ??

Comment: where will i insert this statement sir?